# What is the best post-hoc test to use after a two-way anova has shown there is only a significant effect when including 0 as a factor level?

Tags: anova, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test, two-way, dunnett

I have two factors: A and B, and a response, y.

For factor A I have 3 levels: 300,400,500.
For factor B I have 3 levels: 0.5, 0.6, 0.7.

I carried out an experiment with each combination of these two levels, with two replicates at each combination. e.g. 2 replicates at A=300, B=0.5.

I also carried out one run where I used 300 for factor A and 0 for factor B, as a negative control.

When I carry out a two-way anova without the negative control, I see that neither factor A or B have a statistically significant effect. However, when I add the negative control into the anova, I see that factor B does have a significant effect.

I interpret this as factor B being necessary, but whether it is at level 0.5, 0.6, or 0.7 doesn't really matter.

Would it be data-dredging to compare the negative control against each other group of B using a Dunnett’s Method, given that I know from the anova I don't need to compare between the levels of B? Instead, should I be doing a Tukey-Kramer test to do a fully pairwise comparison?

Here are my data:

| A | B | Repeat | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 0 | 1 | 9.25926E-14 |
| 300 | 0.5 | 1 | 0.08715582 |
| 300 | 0.5 | 2 | 0.06732722 |
| 300 | 0.6 | 1 | 0.08211434 |
| 300 | 0.6 | 2 | 0.07956923 |
| 300 | 0.7 | 1 | 0.07610458 |
| 300 | 0.7 | 2 | 0.0878452 |
| 400 | 0.5 | 1 | 0.06887472 |
| 400 | 0.5 | 2 | 0.08528097 |
| 400 | 0.6 | 1 | 0.08432291 |
| 400 | 0.6 | 2 | 0.08456375 |
| 400 | 0.7 | 1 | 0.08599037 |
| 400 | 0.7 | 2 | 0.08738642 |
| 500 | 0.5 | 1 | 0.08261164 |
| 500 | 0.5 | 2 | 0.09247686 |
| 500 | 0.6 | 1 | 0.07956923 |
| 500 | 0.6 | 2 | 0.1032451 |
| 500 | 0.7 | 1 | 0.08875319 |
| 500 | 0.7 | 2 | 0.09031232 |